# Is there a way to calculate the permittivity of an alloy of two materials with the Lorentz Drude model for both of the materials separately?

Tags: optics, solid-state-physics, models

So the [Lorentz Drude Model](https://optiwave.com/optifdtd-manuals/fdtd-lorentz-drude-model/) is a model for the permittivity of a material. You typically fit several parameters to experimental data of the permittivity: a set of oscillator (bound electron) frequencies, a damping coefficient for each of them, and a weight for each one. Also, a few other variables for the Drude part.

So imagine you have two materials, A and B, you've fitted the LD Model for each of them separately, and you're pretty confident that the fits are accurate (you haven't used too many oscillators, it matches the data, some of the oscillators even match known transitions, etc). Now, is there a way to find the LD parameters for an alloy of A and B based on the ones you fitted for them separately?

Of course, I mean something other than just starting over and fitting the mixture by itself. I'm looking for something like "often several of the oscillators will stay, but others will leave" or something similar. Mostly just any sort of reference I can read about. Is there any sort of method for this?

Comment: Given that even something 'simple' like conductivity is not a nice linear function of alloy composition, this seems unlikely.

Comment: @JonCuster that makes sense. But I'd guess that something like conductivity is definitely continuous, and probably monotonic between two extremes of 100% material A/0% material B, vs 0%A/100%B. So maybe there's at least a function that connects those two points.

Comment: Actually, it is probably not monotonic, since scattering is the key question. I could imagine a conductivity minimum at some intermediate composition.  Then there is the whole question of short range ordering in various alloys that could make, say, a 50-50 composition have less scattering than others. A very complex question.

Comment: You might start with https://srd.nist.gov/JPCRD/jpcrd221.pdf which gives data  on 10 binary systems as well as a discussion of various models.

Comment: Note that some are monotonic, some are not...

Answer (score 0):

The most important parameter in the Drude model is the scattering time of the conduction electrons. Scattering is low in pure metals like copper and aluminum (especially at low temperatures). Alloying causes impurity scattering. It is much stronger in brass than in pure zinc or copper. The scattering time is much longer in 24 karat gold than in alloys with silver. Or in pure aluminum compared with the alloys with magnesium etc that are used in construction.

This affects both electrical and thermal conductivity (Wiedemann-Franz law, the Lorenz number).

There are models to treat properties of alloys, like the Miedema model. But not for conductivity. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miedema%27s_Model